# Can a class decorator receive both the constructor function and additional arguments?

Tags: javascript, class, decorator, ecmascript-next

I've been playing with Babel and decorators. For example:

```
function test(target) { 
}

@test
class A {}
```

My concern is if there's some way to use a decorator against a class and also be able to give arguments to the so-called decorator and don't lose the chance to get the constructor function as first argument:

```
function test(target, arg1, argN) {
   // target will be "hello", arg1 will be "world" and argN undefined,
   // while I would expect target to be the constructor function
}

@test("hello", "world")
class A {}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see how it works?

Comment: @torazaburo Why don't you read my question carefully? :D See the comment inside `test` function. Don't you think I've tried myself already?

Comment: Hello, I don't know exactly what you tried, but if you had run your program via babel-node or similar, you would have received an error message "undefined is not a function" or the equivalent. From that one might deduce, with the help of looking at the transpiled code if necessary, that the problem is that `@test("hello", "world')` is undefined, since you are not returning anything from `test`, whereas it should evaluate to a function to which the object being decorated will be passed.

Comment: @torazaburo Wrong, it was working as I described in my question body... Maybe you're describing what an actual ES2015 would throw in my case, but if I'm not mistaken, the whole sample behaves as I described in my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works this way

```
function test(target, arg1, argN) {
  return function(clazz) {
     console.log(target, arg1, clazz)
  } 
}

@test("hello", "world")
class A {}
```